# Maintain $ (dollar sign) when performing find and replace

Tags: regex, bash, perl

My script appends a block of text to the end of a file.

```
### Start My Block
$IPT -A INPUT -s 8.8.8.8 -j ACCEPT
$IPT -A INPUT -s 8.8.8.4 -j ACCEPT
### End My Block
```

If my text block doesn't exists, it successfully appends the file as shown above using the following:

```
HEAD="### Start My Block"
TAIL="### End My Block"
REPLACEMENT_CONTENT="
\$IPT -A INPUT -s 8.8.8.8 -j ACCEPT
\$IPT -A INPUT -s 8.8.8.4 -j ACCEPT"

echo -e "$HEAD" >> $FILE
echo -e "$REPLACEMENT_CONTENT" >> $FILE
echo -e "$TAIL" >> $FILE
```

If my text block exists, it attempts to replace the block's contents using the following:

```
HEAD="### Start My Block"
TAIL="### End My Block"
REPLACEMENT_CONTENT="
\$IPT -A INPUT -s 4.4.4.4 -j ACCEPT
\$IPT -A INPUT -s 4.4.2.2 -j ACCEPT"

perl -0777 -i -pe "s/($HEAD).*(\\n$TAIL)/\$1$REPLACEMENT_CONTENT\\$2/s" $FILE
```

The problem is I lose the "$IPT" and end up using the following:

```
### Start My Block
 -A INPUT -s 4.4.4.4 -j ACCEPT
 -A INPUT -s 4.4.2.2 -j ACCEPT
### End My Block
```

When I output the above via ">>", with the dollar sign escaped \$, the $IPT is included.  When I revisit the file to replace existing content between the $HEAD and $TAIL and use the perl function with an updated block, the escaped dollar sign doesn't seem to hold.  My guess is it's being interpreted and I'm not sure how to prevent that if escaping isn't enough.

Does anyone know how I can modify the command above to maintain the "$IPT"?

Comment: What's in the variables `HEAD`, `TAIL`, and `REPLACEMENT_CONTENT`? Or do you seriously expect us to be mindreaders?

Comment: Thank you!  Triple escaping did the trick!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you are right your `$IPT` get interpreted in your regex inside perl.

So, using `\$IPT` this you are escaping `$` for the shell. But you also need to escape `$` for perl, so that it shouldn't interpret. For that you should do like this:

```
REPLACEMENT_CONTENT="
\\\$IPT -A INPUT -s 8.8.8.8 -j ACCEPT
\\\$IPT -A INPUT -s 8.8.8.4 -j ACCEPT"
```

This escapes `\` once and then `$` itself sending perl `\$` and thus it did not get interpreted.

**OR**

Just wrap `REPLACEMENT_CONTENT` in single quotes.

```
REPLACEMENT_CONTENT='
\$IPT -A INPUT -s 8.8.8.8 -j ACCEPT
\$IPT -A INPUT -s 8.8.8.4 -j ACCEPT'
```

And after that `perl` part:

```
perl -0777 -i -pe "s/($HEAD).*($TAIL)/\$1$REPLACEMENT_CONTENT\n\$2/s" $FILE
```